# Loop through a sentence

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, do-while

I want to find a sentence with blue text in it, select the entire sentence and remove the blue words one by one. My code only removes the first blue word in a sentence before it moves on to the With statement.

I am looking for something like this pseudo code: 
 **While objSelectionChange.Sentences(1).Find.Font.Color = wdColorBlue**
It would be a nested while loop for just the currently selected sentence

```
Do While True
objSelectionChange.Find.Forward = True
objSelectionChange.Find.Format = True
objSelectionChange.Find.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
objSelectionChange.Find.Execute
If objSelectionChange.Find.Found Then
    strg2 = objSelectionChange.Sentences(1).Text
    count = count + 1
    ReDim strgArray(count)
    strgArray(count) = objSelectionChange.Text
    MsgBox strgArray(count) & " Located In Array Index # " & count
    MsgBox strg2
    strg3 = Replace(strg2, strgArray(count), "")
    strg3 = Replace(strg3, "  ", " ")
    strg3 = Mid(strg3, 1, Len(strg3) - 2)
    MsgBox strg3
Else
    Exit Do
End If
    Set objRangeOrig = objDocOrig.Content
    '''''Search the string in the original manual'''''
    With objRangeOrig.Find
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchPhrase = True
    .IgnoreSpace = True
    .IgnorePunct = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Text = strg3
    .Replacement.Text = Left(strg2, Len(strg2) - 2)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End With
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the replace, `.Replacement.Text` is just a plain text string with no formatting. Any subsequent blue words are being replaced by color=Automatic words (probably black). That's why the Find can't find anything after the first replacement.

Here's a way you can do it without Find and Replace. I think it accomplishes what you want, but you may have to tweak it for your situation.

```
Dim rSearch As Range

Set rSearch = ThisDocument.Range

Do
    rSearch.Find.Forward = True
    rSearch.Find.Format = True
    rSearch.Find.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    rSearch.Find.Execute
    If rSearch.Find.Found Then
        rSearch.Delete wdWord, 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: This would work if I just needed to delete the words, but I need to match 2 strings exactly. That is why I am removing the blue words. The original string is the string without the blue words in which I am comparing. This is hard for me to articulate, and I have actually asked this question before with no luck. Here is a link with the whole story behind my question. I had to try to narrow my question to get a response, which you did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619642/adding-multiple-words-to-a-word-document-in-a-sentence-using-an-array-with-vba

Answer (score -1):

Update objSelectionChange inside the loop, as upon first replace, it can change